# Pronunciation and IPA transcription of "Нева"

Tags: произношение, vowel

I learned different grammar rules. Regarding vowels I learned the rule that there is an "j" added / vowels are spoken with a j if:

- in the beginning of a word (like яблоко [jáblaka])
- after a vowel (as in красивая [kraßíwaja])
- after a ь (like in семья [ßimjá])
- after a ъ   (like in подъезд [padjézd])
- and И after Ь (оладьи [aládji])

In the russian word Нева (the river) the e is reduced, as the a is emphasized. However, none of the above rules applies. As e comes after an Н. Therefore I would not use a j. I would pronounce it as "Niwa", not "Njiwa". When I check the [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0) the audio sound exactly like I expected. However, under pronounciation it says: [nʲɪˈva]. Now my question is, why is there a small "j" added? I would have thought - and at least that is what I hear when I am listening to the audio - that it would be [nɪˈva]?

Comment: To my knowledge there's no such IPA symbol as ß ;) there's a similarly looking voiced bilabial fricative ꞵ but this is not  ß and is used for a completely different phoneme.

Comment: @shabunc - That's how they transcribe the russian letter <C>, IPA [s], on this Geman-language site: https://www.russlandjournal.de/russisch-lernen/schrift-und-aussprache/. In German, S before vowels is always read as [z], so they use the “eszett” symbol ß to make sure the readers pronounce [s] in those words. In German, ß is always read as [s] but cannot be in the word onset: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ß

Comment: @YellowSky well, as one who lives in South Germany  I'd rather say that soft  s and z are allophones, so native German speaker will have hard times telling apart Симон and Зимон. Thank you for the link! - of course one is free in choosing any symbols - all I'm trying to say it's not IPA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most Russian consonants form [pairs “hard” versus “soft”](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology#Consonants), in phonetic terminology it's plain/non-palatalized vs. palatalized, for example **т** vs. **ть**, **н** vs. **нь**, etc. These pairs in IPA look like this: /t/ vs. /tʲ/, /n/ vs. /nʲ/. The small j (ʲ) marks consonant palatalization: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)

Consonants that can be palatalized are pronounced as palatalized before *и, е, ё, ю, я*, and *ь*: ни /nʲi/, не /nʲe/, нё /nʲo/, ню /nʲu/, ня /nʲa/, нь /nʲ/.

These are the basics of [Russian phonology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Russian_phonology) and orthography that can be found in every Russian textbook.

**UPD.:** It's highly recommended that you learn Russian from textbooks that use IPA, or at least learn IPA for Russian at early learning stages. Use [en.wiktionary.org](https://en.wiktionary.org) and [ru.wiktionary.org](https://ru.wiktionary.org), there's good Russian IPA for most words.

Comment: But here in this case is there a consonant palatalization? So for me there is no obvious rule or the rules clearly say that there should be a /n/. This is as the voice in the audio pronounces it. However in the IPA it says with small j. So why is there a palatalization happening here? From my understanding it should be [nɪˈva] and not [nʲɪˈva]. Or: why is it [nʲɪˈva] and not [nɪˈva]?

Comment: Thanks for the update but my question is still there: Why is it [nʲɪˈva] and not [nɪˈva]? And what is the rule saying that a "j" is added here? The voice in the audio does not say [nʲɪˈva]? It says it without a j?

Comment: @BertHobe - I told you, it's a **rule**: ни is **always** /nʲi/ (stressed) or /nʲɪ/ (not stressed). **Always**. It's a **rule**. Why your textbook doesn't mention it is completely due to the quality of the textbook: it simplifies things. How does it give the pronunciation of _тётя_ and _дядя_, I wonder?

Comment: @BertHobe - In fact, it's very difficult, often impossible for Russian native speakers to pronounce /ni/ or /nɪ/, without palatalization. When they try to do it, they actually say either /nʲi/ or /nɨ/.

Comment: According to your profile you can speak German too. Here is the resource (it is a very common resource): https://www.russlandjournal.de/russisch-lernen/schrift-und-aussprache/ (directly in the beginning the first section). There you can see it. And I am not sure if I understood you correctly. According to these rules stated on this webiste and as the voice in the audio says there is no j added. Only in the IPA?

Comment: @BertHobe - Exactly, no /j/ is added in pronunciation, but still the consonant changes, it's not the plain /n/ anymore, and /nʲ/ is **one** sound, not two, the small ʲ doesn't mean a separate sound, it shows that it's not actually /n/, it shows the consonant is _palatalized_, Read this very attentively: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palatalization_(phonetics)

Comment: Thanks for this comment. I see, I think this comment is the actual answer to my question.

Answer (score 0):

> However, under pronounciation it says: [nʲɪˈva]

Because IPA was not designed for Russian language, it is intended for English only. That's why they use this "ʲ" sign even where there is no /j/ sound. It indicates the consonant /n/ is soft.

You should learn and use the Russian transcription system, called "phonetic analysis" (фонетический разбор). It is taught in Russian schools.